# Cannot open xml file error in cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin

When trying to run an .exe file with a corresponding xml file in Cygwin, I get

```
Error: Cannot open xml file /cygdrive/c/users/file.xml from dir C:/users/directory  L33 @ XmlReader.cpp
```

The file is in the specified place...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the executable trying to open the XML file a cygwin or Windows executable? Looks like you're passing a cygwin path to a Windows executable.